# Accessing ASAN’s runtime flags from custom allocator

Tags: c, memory-management, address-sanitizer

AddressSanitizer (ASAN) has APIs for [poisoning and unpoisoning memory](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerManualPoisoning), intended for integration with a custom allocator. In my ([obstack](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Obstacks.html)-like) allocator, I’d also like to respect some of the relevant [runtime flags](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerFlags#run-time-flags), such as `malloc_fill_byte`, `redzone`, and `max_redzone`. Is there a way to access those without duplicating the parsing and priority logic inside the ASAN libraries?

Comment: You'll probly have more luck asking this in https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues